# value of max_connections in AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, rds

does anyone know where I can found the highest value of max_connections in AWS RDS? I'm primarily interested in the db.t2 instances running MySQL. 
I cannot find any appropriate link about that.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @error2007s states you can find it in the console, just to complete, in a more general way you have:

- t2.micro 66
- t2.small 150
- m3.medium    296
- t2.medium    312
- m3.large 609
- t2.large 648
- m4.large 648
- m3.xlarge    1237
- r3.large 1258
- m4.xlarge    1320
- m2.xlarge    1412
- m3.2xlarge   2492
- r3.xlarge    2540

Taken from [here](http://tritoneco.com/2015/11/23/max_connections-at-aws-rds-mysql-instance-sizes/)

Answer (score 5):

When you go to configuration details of your RDS you will find a Parameter Group in the details. Click on that parameter group.

[image]

In that parameter group search for `max_connections` you will get the value.

[image]